# How can I update this db_query statement to db_insert for D7?

Tags: 7, database

I'm trying to update someone's module to D7, but I'm unsure of how to convert the usage of places and values in the query to use 7's api properly.

```
$fields = implode(',', array_keys($args));
$places = implode(',', array_fill(0, count($args), "'%s'"));
$values = array_values($args);

$insert_result = db_query(
  'INSERT INTO {bluga_request}(' . $fields . ') VALUES (' . $places . ')', $values
);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard way is to use the [`db_insert()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_insert/7) function with an associative array of field names/values:

```
$fields = array(
  'id' => $id,
  'name' => $name
);

db_insert('bluga_request')->fields($fields)->execute();
```

It actually looks like in your case the fields are already set up as an associative array in `$args` so you would just do this:

```
db_insert('bluga_request')->fields($args)->execute();
```

Comment: that would work, but I'm not sure what `VALUES (' . $places . ')', $values` does can you explain that part so that I can adjust the $fields array?

Comment: At the moment your code is splitting up an associative array into two comma separated strings (one for field names, one for values)...this is done so it can be inserted directly into the SQL query string. Using the query builder you don't have to do this, you can just pass your original `$args` associative array to the `->fields()` method. The updated answer has a code example :)

Comment: p.s. `$places` refers to a comma separated list of placeholders (`%s`) which were used in Drupal 6 to perform string replacement for the arguments in the query

Comment: @Arosboro Suppose `$fields` contains two items; then, `$places` will contain `"'%s','%s'"`. If `$fields` contains six items, then `$places` will contain `"'%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s'"`.